# When printing, Vuetify application reserves space for invisible elements

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I created an application using Vue.JS and Vuetify. The layout is based on the Google Contacts layout. I am using both a toolbar and a navigation drawer.

I would like to be able to print the content from the browser without printing the toolbar and nav drawer. I created the following CSS class:

@media print {

```
.no-print {
    display: none;
}
```

}

I applied this class to the toolbar and nav drawer. When I try to print the page, these elements don't show up in the print preview, which is good, but the content does not stretch to the entire page. Looks like the toolbar and nav drawer space is still reserved for these elements.

How can I remove this space reservation?

Comment: Can you include your vue/html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space is reserved with padding on v-content, so you'll have to add

```
.v-content {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

to your media query.

Comment: maybe it's due to an update, but the class is now called "v-content"

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Kael's answer, I added this to my my main App.vue compononent:

```
<style scoped>
@media print{
    .v-content {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}   
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick for me on the layout page.

```
@media print {
    .v-main {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```